# Working with In command and group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

I am trying to fetch some data out of two tables (department and person),
my work is basically with `in` clause. Could anybody help me identify the problem in the following query?

```
from email.department, email.person
where person.works_in in (select person.works_in from email.person
             having salary > avg(person.salary) group by (person.works_in));

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 16:              having salary > avg(salary) group by (person.wo.

I am getting the above error

UPDATED: 
select person.works_in from email.person                    
group by person.salary,person.works_in
having salary > avg(salary);

the query is executed but, Now, I get nothing in the return value.
```

Comment: `group by` comes before `having`

Comment: @Nick Please have a look in the updated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks to me that you want to select people that have `salary` above average. You can achieve it without using `group by` and `having`. I assumed that there is one row per person in your table.

```
select works_in
from email.person
where salary > (select AVG(salary) from email.person)
```